# JavaScript text to find the path of a link

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using next.js and I have the following page structure, the value is stored in `path`

```
www.mysite.com/countries
www.mysite.com/countries/africa
www.mysite.com/countries/asia
www.mysite.com/countries/europe
```

I have sub pages under each page - value is stored in `slug`:

```
www.mysite.com/countries/africa/sudan
www.mysite.com/countries/africa/kenya
...
```

I want to check if slug is in the path:

```
slug.includes(path)
```

if the slug is `www.mysite.com/countries/africa` this also returns true for `www.mysite.com/countries` which I dont want.

I just want `www.mysite.com/countries/africa` and `www.mysite.com/countries/africa/[any countries]`, I tried different ways but cant get this condition right.

Answer (score 0):

I use regex `const regex = /countries\/(.*)\/(.*)|countries\/(.*)/;` to filter `path = window.location.pathname`. For example, I will set path manually.

You can check the below demo:

```js
// Runing on real environment
// var path = window.location.pathname;

// Path start with /
// Uncomment to try the below example
// var path = '/countries/africa/sudan'; 
var path = '/countries/africa';

const regex = /countries\/(.*)\/(.*)|countries\/(.*)/;
var result = path.match(regex);

if (result) {

  const land = result[1] !== undefined ? result[1] : result[3];
  const country = result[2];

  if (land == 'africa') {
    if (country !== undefined) {
      // this match for www.mysite.com/countries/africa/[any countries]
      console.log('matched to country of africa URL');
    } else {
      // this match for www.mysite.com/countries/africa
      console.log('matched to africa URL');
    }
  } else {
    console.log('not matched to africa URL');
  }
} else {
  console.log('not matched');
}
```

Comment: thanks, I want to set it up so it is more dynamic, since there are many countries, I cant setup if conditions for `asia` , or `america` and so on, that would be many cases

Comment: @RainMan it's ok. Please includes all conditions in your answers next time. That will make everything to be more clear. Anyway, hope you can make it soon.